# unable to convert date format Mon Jul 23 2018 21:54:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) to YYYYMMDD

Tags: javascript

here i have a json data given format

```
var data = [Mon Jul 16 2018 21:54:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Mon Jul 16 2018 21:54:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)]
```

and how can i convert it into

```
classname(20180716,20180716)
```

i tried using split method for converting the data into array but i failed any suggestions

i followed join and split methods also

```
function convert(str) {
    var date = new Date(str),
        mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
        day  = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return [ date.getFullYear(), mnth, day ].join("-");
}

convert("Thu Jun 09 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data` as below:

```
var data = [
  "Mon Jul 16 2018 21:54:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
  "Mon Jul 16 2018 21:54:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
];
```

Separating the lines using a semi-colon works for me:

```js
function convert(str) {
  var date = new Date(str);
  var mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-");
}

console.log(convert("Thu Jun 09 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"));
```

The key is to declare `date` separately.

Output:

```
2018-06-08
```

To do for an array of all dates:

```js
function convert(str) {
  var date = new Date(str);
  var mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-");
}
var data = [
  "Mon Jul 16 2018 21:54:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
  "Mon Jul 16 2018 21:54:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
];
console.log(data.map(convert));
```

Also note that the `data` should contain array of strings.

Comment: in the data variable var data = [
  Mon Jul 16 2018 21:54:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
  Mon Jul 16 2018 21:54:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
]; will be like this only

Comment: @2Developer That's not a valid one then.